# javascript - unexpected token?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add loading gif while uploading photos.
Here is my JavaScript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function call(tab) {
        $(".loading").html("<center><br><br><img src=\"icons/processing.gif\" /><br><br></center>").load(tab);

    }
</script>
```

This is how I call the function :

```
<div class="loading"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" name="take_photo" id="take_photo" class="take-photo" onchange="submit(); call('survey_edit.php?id='<?$id;?>'&step=photo')">
            <label for="take_photo"><figure><img src="icons/camera.png"></figure> <span><?=v("take_photo");?>&hellip;</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?=$f->input("back",v("back"),"type='button' onclick=\"window.location='?step=2&id=".$id."';\"","btn btn-warning");?>
            <?=$f->input("finish",v("finish"),"type='button' onclick=\"window.location='mysurvey.php';\" style='position:relative;float:right;'","btn btn-primary");?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It shows the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? "

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your source code looks broken in .form-group . Also, `center` is long deprecated. There are better ways of doing that which are more current. Is that PHP in there? It could be your web server isn't setup correctly.

Comment: Is the second part php?  If so then show then final html code that is send to the server. But most likely ther error is here `?id='<?$id;?>'&step=` the `'` right before the `<?` will end the string in js, and then the string is compared (`<`)  with `?` and that `?` is then a unexpected token.

Comment: @t.niese I just realized the PHP too.

Comment: @t.niese thanks for your explanation the error is clear, but my loading gif is not showing yet. any advise?

Comment: @payket thats a different question, and as of that has to be asked as new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the comment the problem was with this line:

```
<input type="file" name="take_photo" id="take_photo" class="take-photo" onchange="submit(); call('survey_edit.php?id='<?$id;?>'&step=photo')">
```

The problem here is that the `'` right before the `<?` will end the string in js, and `<?`  should be `<?=`, because otherwise `<?$i?>` would not be replace by php with the value of `$i`.

So then the string is compared (`<`) with `?` and that `?` is then a unexpected token.

```
<input type="file" name="take_photo" id="take_photo" class="take-photo" onchange="submit(); call('survey_edit.php?id=<?=$id;?>&step=photo')">
```

Answer (score 1):

You event of onchange should be looking like this:
`onchange="submit(); call('survey_edit.php?id=<?=$id?>&step=photo')"`